# Conditionally set SSL certificate request header in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache 2.4 server configured as a reverse proxy to accept incoming HTTPS requests and reverse-proxy them to another server over HTTP with custom HTTP headers containing any provided client certificate information.

A simplified version of my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/server.key"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/path/to/client-ca-chain.pem"
  SSLVerifyClient optional

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://remote-server/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://remote-server/
  RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Port 443
  RequestHeader set Client-Cert-Subject "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
</VirtualHost>
```

For the most part, this is fine, but things get a little weird because Certificate Authentication is optional.

When a user provides their certificate, the remote system sees the `Client-Cert-Subject` header just as I'd expect:

```
Client-Cert-Subject: CN=USER.NAME.0123456789,OU=BLAH,O=WHATEVER,C=STUFF
```

When a user doesn't provide their certificate, e.g. by clicking "Cancel" instead of their certificate when prompted by the browser, the header is still included but contains the text string `(null)`:

```
Client-Cert-Subject: (null)
```

This makes the remote server very angry.

What I'd like to do is include the header, complete with the certificate subject retrieved using `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s`, when the user provides one, but just not include the header at all if the user didn't provide a certificate. It would also be acceptable, although weird?, if the header was provided as an empty string when is no certificate information.

I've tried various iterations of using an `If` directive, e.g.

```
<If "-n %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s">
  RequestHeader set Client-Cert-Subject "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
</If>
```

and of using an expression on the RequestHeader directive, e.g.

```
  RequestHeader set Client-Cert-Subject "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s" expr="-n %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
```

but always get either a syntax error, always the header, or never the header.

How can I coerce apache to conditionally include my `Client-Cert-Subject` only when there's actually a client certificate?

Answer (score 2):

The example of [Header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) expression shows that the entire parameter has to be quoted ("expr=..." instead of expr="...").
I ended up with

```
 RequestHeader set X-SSL-CLIENT-CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s" "expr=-n %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}"
```

and this worked, the "null" string didn't occur anymore (Apache 2.4.6).